# UserControl asp.net

Tags: asp.net, c#

Доброго времени суток. Не подскажете, как создать user control, чтобы он мог взаимодействовать с сервером? При попытке добавить user control, который внутри содержит контрол, содержащий runet="server", выдает ошибку при загрузке страницы

> `Control 'ctl04_LinkButton1' of type 'LinkButton' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.`

Добавляю контрол таким образом

```
Control contr = Page.LoadControl("WebUserControl1");
```

Содержание контрола

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication24.WebUserControl1" %>

<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server"  onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Это все глючная долбанная visualStudo 10   в 8ке все прекрасно. Всем спасибо..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст ошибки говорит, что контрол должен быть размещен внутри тэгов form. То есть, если на странице есть форма

```
<form id="MyForm" runat="server">
    <!-- Мы должные добавиться сюда -->
</form>
```

контрол должен добавиться внутрь тэгов `<form></form>`. По-умолчанию с LinkButton это не происходит. Можно попробовать добавляться внутрь формы так:

```
HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm)FindControl("MyForm");

MyForm.Controls.Add(contr);
```